# refreshText widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to create an update of my text widget in tkinter .

```
def affichage_update ():

    with open('archives/monitor1_loc35L.txt') as monitor1, open('archives/monitor2_loc35L.txt') as monitor2:

        s= Scrollbar(generalites)

        T= Text(generalites,bg='powder blue',width=450,height=350,font=('arial',14,'bold'))
        s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        s.config(command=T.yview)
        T.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)
        while True:
            line1 = monitor1.readline()
            if len(line1) == 0:
                break
            line1 = line1.strip().split()
            line2 = monitor2.readline()
            line2 = line2.strip().split()
            T.insert(END, f'{line1[0]:15}\t {line1[1]:10}\t\t {line2[1]:10}\n')
    T.after(1000, affichage_update)
affichage_update()
```

I would like help to find a solution to the automatic update of the content of my Text widget for example every 1 second
thanks

Comment: For automatically updating text box or any filed for that matter you should look into `after()`. It is the built in method from tkinter that is used for timed events.

Comment: it's wrote in the code , but the content of the text is refreshed one first ime and not every second

Comment: You will need to add an `after` statement inside of your function so the function calls itself at a regular interval.

Comment: this line do what you tell I think :T_generalites_loc35L_axe_bottom_loc35L.after(1000, affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update)

Comment: Try this instead: `generalites_bottom_loc35L.after(1000, affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update ()`. You will also need to do the text creation and placement outside of the function and then do updates on the text only inside the function.

Comment: I don't understaind you : the name of my fonction is : affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update. to call it with after, I use like this: T_generalites_loc35L_axe_bottom_loc35L.after(1000, affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update)

Comment: You should call after on the container instead of the widget inside the function.

Comment: can you please indicate me some lines to rectify my code

Comment: Not with the way your example is now. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Comment: I do that but does'nt work: affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update()
T_generalites_loc35L_axe_bottom_loc35L.after(1000, affichage_ddm_axe_loc35L_update)

Comment: please read the link I provided so you can understand what a MCVE is. This question is not testable as is.

Comment: I just minimize my code

Answer (score 0):

My answer should help you 2 ways here.

1. To show you what a minimum example looks like.
2. To provide some detail on how to use `after()`.

Please in the future use a MCVE for questions. You will need your imports a root window and the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

This example should help:

```
import tkinter as tk

generalites = tk.Tk()
s = tk.Scrollbar(generalites)
T = tk.Text(generalites)
s.pack(side="right", fill="y")
T.pack(side="left", fill="y")
s.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)

def affichage_update():
    with open('archives/monitor1_loc35L.txt') as monitor1, open('archives/monitor2_loc35L.txt') as monitor2:
        while True:
            line1 = monitor1.readline()
            if len(line1) == 0:
                break
            line1 = line1.strip().split()
            line2 = monitor2.readline()
            line2 = line2.strip().split()
            T.insert("end", f'{line1[0]:15}\t {line1[1]:10}\t\t {line2[1]:10}\n')
    T.after(1000, affichage_update)

affichage_update()
generalites.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

my code is so long and I have minimized it :
generalites is a tab of the notebook
so I think I can't write the last line : generalites.mainloop()
because there is'nt yet the end of my code
at the first picture, I must to write data into labelframe
[add data into labelframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BnQE.jpg)

and I will to recieve the informations and write it into text by textfiles
like this picture
[data in Text widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EQaD.jpg)